# C - Investigating stack and heap contents program

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

How would I go about writing a C program that lists ALL the contents of stack and heap including its own variables and mallocations ?

The purpose of it is for me to be able to see what's going on in the memory as I write and test code.

Comment: You need something that can read and parse the program's debug information (if any), otherwise you'll never identify the variables.

Comment: Plus one, nothing wrong with an intriguing question in my opinion.

Comment: As pointed out by Bathsheba, it cannot be done by using the C specification alone. You need to use platform-specific constructs. So, to make sense, you question should pinpoint the platform you are targeting.

Comment: About the purpose, use a debugger. What you want to do is not trivial, especially if you want it to be resilient enough to not crash when some bug trashes the memory. And I just said "resilient", not "useful".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The c standard doesn't explicitly mention a stack or a heap. That, along with the fact that variable and function names are compiled out, means that your task is impossible.

You *could* build your own compiler which would effectively be a debugging tool. But that would be ridiculous as such a thing would take a long time to build and you'd have to adapt it constantly as the standard evolves. Or you could use the output of a compiler that generates debugging symbols.

Better still, learn to use a good debugger.

Comment: Okay I've just realized my question was a bit too wild and it came as curiosity and seeing that my IDE doesn't offer any sort of "map" where I could see what happened in a memory when I play around with pointers/variables and so on. Thanks for the answer.